# Qt include Class of another Project (Cannot open include file: 'foo.h')

Tags: c++, qt, include, project

I just started with Qt and some issues came up. I'm sure it must be a simple solution but I just can't find it.

I have two Projects, ProjectOne and ProjectTwo. I'd like you use the class foo from ProjectOne in main.cpp from ProjectTwo. When I run my Programm The Files are copied/referenced into ProjectTwo, but when i try to include foo in my main.cpp (`#include "foo.h"`) i recieve the following error:

---

```
> main.cpp:3: error: C1083: Cannot open include file: 'foo.h':
> No such file or directory
```

---

Here's my Structure:

```
-ProjectOne
    -ProjectOne.pro
    -Headers
        -foo.h
    -Source
        -foo.cpp
    -Other files
        -ProjectOne.pri
-ProjectTwo
    -ProjectTwo.pro
    -ProjectOne
        -ProjectOne.pri
        -Headers
            -foo.h
        -Sources
            -foo.cpp
    -Sources
        main.cpp
```

---

Here's what i edited on my .pro and .pri files

```
**ProjectOne.pri**
INCLUDEPATH  += $$PWD
SOURCES      += $$PWD/foo.cpp
HEADERS      += $$PWD/foo.h

**ProjectTwo.pro:**
include(../ProjectOne/ProjectOne.pri)
QT += core
SOURCES += foo.cpp
HEADERS += foo.h
```

---

I'm using Qt Creator 3.1.2 on Windows 7. My Programming Language is C++ and I'm compiling with VisualStudio 10 Express.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you show me the line where you include foo.h in you main.cpp

Comment: thanks for the reply! the line is: `#include "foo.h"`

Comment: looks like your compiler doesn't know where to find foo.h. see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When including a file that isn't directly in you project folder you need to include it with full or relative path.

i.e.

```
#include "bar/foo.h"
```

or

```
#include "../../bar/foo.h"
```

Comment: I changed the Include statement in main.cpp to `#include "../ProjectOne/foo.h"`and it worked! Thank you so much! I hope you don't mind me asking: Do I also need to add any Libs? Because now I get an unresolved external symbol error..

Comment: I'm sorry but i can't see the problem without more code. maybe this could help you http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/799kze2z.aspx

Comment: @oemay, yes, you have to add lib. Just modify your .pro file by adding LIBS += -L"path_to_your_lib_without_name" -l[libname]